# why Dialog doesn't show in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog, floating-action-button

I want to create a Dialog window when I click the Floating Action Button. But, when I click the button, just appears the Toast message.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
    val users = ArrayList<User>()

    users.add(User("John", "USA"))

    val adapter = CustomAdapter(users)

    recyclerView.adapter = adapter

    fab.setOnClickListener {
        val dialog = Dialog(this)
        Toast.makeText(this, "It's working...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_add)
        dialog.setTitle("Add person")
        dialog.setCancelable(false)

        val nameText = dialog.findViewById(R.id.name) as EditText
        val addressText = dialog.findViewById(R.id.address) as EditText
        val btnAdd = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_ok) as Button
        val btnCancel = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel) as Button

        btnAdd.setOnClickListener{
            users.add(User(nameText.text.toString(), addressText.text.toString()))
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            dialog.dismiss()
        }
        btnCancel.setOnClickListener {
            dialog.dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

How can I change the code so it show the Dialog Window when I click the FAB?

UPDATE:
You guys're right! It worked just fine after I put dialog.show(). Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to invoke show() on dialog.
dialog.show()

Answer (score 0):

You need to call dialog.show(). Just call it anywhere below dialog.setCancelable(false).

Answer (score 0):

You have to invoke `show()` like the following.

```
//...
dialog.setTitle("Add person")
dialog.setCancelable(false)
// ...
btnAdd.setOnClickListener{
    //...
}
btnCancel.setOnClickListener {
    dialog.dismiss()
}

//show dialog adding below line.
dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

After create dialog , we need to call show method to show dialog on screen

Add This line after create dialog `dialog.show()`

Please replace or add this code

```
recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
    val users = ArrayList<User>()

    users.add(User("John", "USA"))

    val adapter = CustomAdapter(users)

    recyclerView.adapter = adapter

    fab.setOnClickListener {
        val dialog = Dialog(this)
        Toast.makeText(this, "It's working...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_add)
        dialog.setTitle("Add person")
        dialog.setCancelable(false)

        val nameText = dialog.findViewById(R.id.name) as EditText
        val addressText = dialog.findViewById(R.id.address) as EditText
        val btnAdd = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_ok) as Button
        val btnCancel = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel) as Button

        btnAdd.setOnClickListener{
            users.add(User(nameText.text.toString(), addressText.text.toString()))
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            dialog.dismiss()
        }
        btnCancel.setOnClickListener {
            dialog.dismiss()
        }
    //add this line 
     //Call show() method to show dialog 
  dialog.show()
    }
}
```